# Keychain returned the following status: -34018

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, keychain

My application crashes sometimes on iOS 9 devices, and it is showing the following error.

> [FATAL] [WORKLIGHT] Uncaught Exception: Keychain returned the following status: -34018
>   2017-01-02 12:37:19.490 FlightCrew[2944:1081505] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Unable to generate key pair.', reason: 'Keychain returned the following status: -34018'

Comment: It is probably much easier finding existing articles and post about this problem if you use the error message "Unable to generate key pair" instead of, or in conjunction with, the error code. Did you try that?

Comment: I believe this to be a duplicate of the above question. However one way to solve it is to make sure that Keychain Sharing is enabled in Xcode > Capabilities.

Comment: i have enabled it and it works fine in iOS10 not in iOS 9.